# Run org-store-link after renaming file with dired?

Tags: org-mode, dired

When in a dired buffer, I use `R` or `dired-do-rename` to move files from one directory to another (typically my "refile" directory to where the file(s) actually belong(s)).

When I do this I'd like to store an org-link using `org-store-link` to the "refiled" document(s) in it's/their new location preferable using th prefix argument, `C-u`.

Any idea how to accomplish this? Ideally it would work for a single or multiple files marked with `m`. If performing this action on multiple files, all links should be stored.

I imagine this is possible with `defadvice` since I can't find any obvious hooks but don't have the experience to implement it.

Comment: I suggest defining a new command and bind that, instead of advising.

Comment: I think that's a good idea too. Any idea which function I could use to get the new file path?

Comment: Good question. When renaming, dired adds a mark to the destination file. It seems `dired-add-file` is responsible for this. You could advise (yes, I know...) that function to make it log/record the filenames it marks into some dynamically scoped variable. Then you can let-bind that variable around the call to dired-do-rename. Not sure if that is super clean, but I don't know better anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I couldn't get it to work with a prefix argument (C-u), I advised `dired-rename-file` to automatically store every renamed file (including those bulk moved using marks) to `org-stored-links` which can then be inserted into an org-mode file with `org-insert-link` using the following:

```
;; Have dired store org-link when a file or files(s) are renamed
(defun my/dired-rename-file (file newname ok-if-already-exists)
  "Store org-link to the renamed file."
  (push (list newname (file-name-nondirectory newname)) org-stored-links))

(advice-add #'dired-rename-file :after #'my/dired-rename-file)
```